# Disable ALL Dell boot Alert messages

Tags: bios, fan, dell-precision, front-panel

I have built a "custom" dell t5400 pc. With this comes a new case and new fans, I am not using any of the original fans or even the original front panel, or the intrusion button being detected, or the cpu being in slot 0, (which can't be changed as the previous owner of the board screw the crap out of socket 0 so the cpu is now in socket 1). I keep getting warning messages on boot, which makes sense since I have removed the fans and front panel, but I need this pc to not ask me to press f1 every time it boots. Is there any way to remove this request for the f1 key or to remove all the alert messages and the f1 key press as well?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will keep prompting you if it doesn't sense the fan.  You might install a multi-fan control unit and put all of the fan leads through it.

Comment: thats a pain since I am not going to get things like a function intrusion button that it wants or a front panel or the cpu cooler that it wants to detect

Comment: If the BIOS also alerts on every boot regarding the missing input from the intrusion button, then please update your question to reflect it.  That's a more difficult problem to solve.